# Changing R.framework/Versions/Current for Mac using terminal commands?

Tags: r, macos, terminal

How to revert to an older version of R (3.5) on Mac (due to an error created in ggplot2 annotate with facets following and update to R 3.6).

Hi, this is my first post here. I should also mention that I don't have any knowledge of coding outside of R.

I recently updated my version of R from 3.5 to 3.6. I was unaware of an issue relating to the use of annotate with faceting created following the update.

I won't pretend to understand exactly what is happening, but it is described here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3305

I haven't been able to find any way around the issue after some browsing (the suggested solution of using labels from the dataframe will not work for me) - but I would prefer to just revert to the old version anyhow rather than rewriting my code.

Apparently its possible to change the version of R being used by RStudio, as described here:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

"To change the current version of R.Framework you can either:

1. Run the installer from CRAN for the R version you want to be current
2. Use the RSwitch utility available at: http://r.research.att.com/
3. Update the R.framework/Versions/Current directory alias directly using ln -s"

I have tried running the installer from CRAN as well as the RSwitch utility. The installer worked corectly, but after installation R would not open and RStudio could not detect R. I don't really understand how to use the RSwitch utility.

I next tried to use the ln -s command, but I am not familiar with terminal commands at all, and couldn't figure it out.

I followed the instructions in this link:

https://codingpad.maryspad.com/2018/02/26/how-to-update-r-and-rstudio-on-mac-os-x/

Code from link: ln -sfhv /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current

But changed the version from '3.3' t0 '3.5'. This did seem to work (or at least do something), but I encountered the same issue as when I reinstalled the older version using the CRAN package.

Any suggestions or help with terminal commands would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE

I have provided a simplified version of my code. I should briefly explain - I realise that I could easily use the strip text at the top to label each species, but higher powers have requested that the species name be placed lower in the panel, as well as having the preferred depth annotation.

FACET CODE EXAMPLE - this should be a reproducible example.

```
### DATA (for example)

abundance <- c( runif(160, min = 0, max = 100)) 

species <- c(replicate(40, "sp.1"), replicate(40, "sp.2"), replicate(40, "sp.3"), replicate(40, "sp.4"))

depth.1 <- c(replicate(10, "0"), replicate(10, "2"), replicate(10, "6"), replicate(10, "10"))
depth <- c(replicate(4, depth.1))

data <- data.frame(abundance, species, depth) 

species.annotate <- unique(data$species) 

pref.depth.annotate <- c("preferred depth: 2", "preferred depth: 6", "preferred depth: 0", "preferred depth: 2")


### (Plot)

gg_example <- ggplot(data, aes(y = abundance, x = depth)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "bar", 
               colour = "black", 
               fill = "white") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, 
               geom = "errorbar", 
               aes(width = 0.3)) +
  annotate("text", label = species.annotate, 
           x = 0.5, y = 68, 
           hjust = 0, 
           fontface = 'italic') +
  annotate("text", label = pref.depth.annotate , 
           x = 0.5, y = 64, 
           hjust = 0)


finalplot <- gg_example + 
  facet_wrap(.~ species) + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(y = c(0, 80))
finalplot
```

I get this error when I run my original code and the example code:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (16): label
```

Comment: Can you share some reproducible & minimal sample code that shows how/where the combination of facets and `annotate` fails for you? In the GitHub issue you're linking to it was decided that a user-side fix was more sensible than a code fix. To cite Claus Wilke *"If we want different labels then the correct way to do this is to integrate them into the data frame and then the problem disappears."* There is no reason to downgrade R for that reason.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Have added an example. I initially thought that it would be simpler to just revert to the old version of R, however I am grateful for any fix at this point. Sorry for asking such a convoluted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the comments, the `ggplot`-way would be to store additional labels in a `data.frame`.

Here is a minimal example, based on your (slightly trimmed) sample code:

```
labels <- data.frame(
    species = unique(data$species),
    label1 = unique(data$species),
    x1 = 1, y1 = 68,
    x2 = 1, y2 = 62,
    label2 = pref.depth.annotate)

ggplot(data, aes(y = abundance, x = depth)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar") +
    geom_text(data = labels, aes(label = label1, x = x1, y = y1), hjust = 0) +
    geom_text(data = labels, aes(label = label2, x = x2, y = y2), hjust = 0) +
    facet_wrap(~ species)
```

[image]

The key is to create a separate `data.frame` (here `labels`) with the same faceting column (here `species`) as your main `data`. We store both labels and coordinates in the additional `data.frame` and can then use `geom_text` with `aes` to plot. Since we use `facet_wrap(~ species)`, and the data for `geom_text` has a `species` column, text will get placed in the corresponding facets.

This approach is consistent with what Claus Wilke suggested in the conclusion of the [issue you linked to](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3305#issuecomment-490989001): *"If we want different labels then the correct way to do this is to integrate them into the data frame and then the problem disappears."*

Comment: Ahh I see what was meant by "integrate into the data frame" now. Thanks so much for your solution!